# Blazor server class library not copying files in wwwroot

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, static-files, wwwroot

I created a Blazor RCL class library that contains some base scripts/icons/styles in `wwwroot` to be added to the main app's `wwwroot` folder when deployed.

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/class-libraries?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio), files are supposed to be *copied automatically* into `wwwroot/_content/My_RCL_Class/`.

When I package my solution (that includes my RCL as well as the main app project) via docker some of the files included in `wwwroot` are indeed present, but not all - I checked project config file and all files are marked as `content - Do not copy`.

How can I ensure files located in the RCL's `wwwroot` folder are indeed copied to the `_content` subfolder?

Comment: Please show the "Relative Path" your actually using and errors resulting to reference the content. As @HenkHolterman pointed out it should just work.

Comment: I check on the docker machine in the `wwwroot` folder and files are missing! Once the file is copied there, scripts/images/styles are loaded correctly! It NOT a reference problem in the code!

Comment: After rebooting, clearing the `obj` and `bin` folder and targetting a new container name, files were eventually copied as expected...